# Execute Command and Now()

Tags: c#, sql, linq-to-sql

```
DataContext.ExecuteCommand("DELETE from Table WHERE Date < Now()");
```

I get an error about how Now() is not a recognized built in function name.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

When you send your SQL query directly to SQL Server, you need to use the SQL Server functions - not the .NET ones.

Use this instead:

```
DataContext.ExecuteCommand("DELETE from Table WHERE Date < GETDATE()");
```

`GETDATE()` is the T-SQL equivalent for Now()

Answer (score 4):

Now() is not TSQL. Use GETDATE() or GETUTCDATE()

Answer (score 2):

Could that be `GetDate()` instead of `Now()`?

Answer (score 1):

You should use `GETDATE()` instead of `NOW()`

Answer (score 1):

I don't think Now() is  a recognized function in SQL.